# Average Pandas Dataframe with condition other Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes. One only contains binary values, the other floats between 0 and 1.
Eg.

```
df1:
         col 1        col 2        col 3        col 4        col 5        col 6        col 7
0          0.0          1.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0  
1          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          1.0          0.0          0.0  
2          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          1.0          0.0          1.0  
3          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          1.0  
4          0.0          0.0          0.0          0.0          1.0          0.0          0.0  
df2:
         col 1        col 2        col 3        col 4        col 5        col 6        col 7  
0     0.068467     0.099870     0.090778     0.087500     0.612955     0.081495     0.570557  
1     0.091651     0.084946     0.082704     0.103070     0.517317     0.092595     0.603526  
2     0.070380     0.104353     0.103062     0.086780     0.598848     0.101543     0.570064  
3     0.052239     0.123760     0.215329     0.087608     0.581883     0.080650     0.574241  
4     0.087564     0.104460     0.125887     0.079945     0.646284     0.081015     0.609308
```

What I need is to compute the average of df1 where df2 >= 0.5 (or any other number)
All I could find on this topic is for columns only and I could not get it to work on the entire dataframe.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is necessary same index and same columns names in both `DataFrame`s.

Then use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for set missing values to False values by mask and then get `mean`:

```
df = df1.where(df2 >= 0.5).mean()
```

If need mean of all values use [numpy.nanmean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) for exclude missing values:

```
mean = np.nanmean(df1.where(df2 >= 0.5))
```

Another idea is convert all values to `Series` with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then get mean:

```
mean = df1.where(df2 >= 0.5).stack().mean()
```

Comment: Awesome. Thats super easy. This prints the average for each column. Getting the overall mean would be nice, too. But since some columns have NaN values (since no value matches the condition), just an  additional  .mean() at the end does not work.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a dataframe with the values above 0.5 included and NaN everywhere else:

```
df = df1.where(df2 >= 0.5)
```

We then calculate the sum of the values and count the number of values to get the mean:

```
sum_values = df.sum().sum()
count_values = df.count().sum()
mean_value = sum_values / count_values
```